# Cell on last row of GridView will not color in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView1 that shows current machines my company is building that have not shipped yet. Cell0 of each row shows the serial number of the machine. The number either ends with [.000] for mechanical or [.00E] for electrical. Within the mechanical products, those divide into four categories - [STD], [BLD], [TLG] and [DIE]. GridView1 comes up with no problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, coding in VB and not C#.  I am color coding the background of cell0 depending on if the machine is [.000] or [.00E] as well as what category it falls under  - [STD], [BLD], [TLG] or [DIE]. Everything works getting the colors to correspond. What doesn't work is I can not get the very last roll of GridView1 to color in the cell0 background. It remains white.

Am I not closing correctly or forgetting a code at the end?

Here's the code where the magic happens.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For Each er As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            'Get the Serial Number out of the first column
            Dim TrimmedJN As String
            TrimmedJN = Trim(er.Cells(0).Text)
            Session("JNPerRow") = TrimmedJN
            SqlDataSource4.DataBind()
            GridView_Code.DataBind()
            Dim TrimmedCode As String
            TrimmedCode = GridView_Code.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text

            If TrimmedJN.EndsWith("00") And TrimmedCode = "TLG" Then
                er.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Orange
            ElseIf TrimmedJN.EndsWith("00") And TrimmedCode = "BLD" Then
                er.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Orange
            ElseIf TrimmedJN.EndsWith("00") And TrimmedCode = "DIE" Then
                er.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Pink
            'Makes everything else light green
            Else : er.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGreen  
            End If
            'Overrides the green to be yellow for Electrical
            If TrimmedJN.EndsWith("0E") Then 
                er.Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
            End If

        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested loop inside the `RowDataBound` event (I assume thats what the snippet is in).

```
For Each er As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
```

The RowDataBound event already loops across all cells. So when the last row is processed by the RowDataBound event it is not yet part of the GridView row collection and therefore the nested loop cannot find it.

Better is to use the source data for comparison in the RowDataBound event.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    'check if the row is a datarow
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

        'cast the row back to a datarowview
        Dim row As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem,DataRowView)

        'get the cell value not from the gridview, but from it's source data
        Dim cellValue As String = row("myColumn").ToString

        'color cells or rows
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red
        e.Row.Cells(0).BackColor = Color.Green

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried the code and it did not work at first. Then I realized the column I was pulling the identifying serial number (we call it a Job Number) from was 15 characters and probably had additional spaces in it, which made identifying how it ended (00 or 0E) wrong. I did a simple trim to [Dim cellValue As String = trim(row("JOBNUM").ToString)] and it worked like a charm. It even solved a reporting problem on another report that was related. You, my friend are a genius. Thank you so much for the help.